# randomise part of an object array

Tags: php, sorting, random

I have an array of object .First I shuffle it.I want to sort array based on two key

```
"questions": [
    {
      "id_question": "35",
      "id_subject": "63",
      "id_question_pattern": "1",
      "correct_marks": "1",
      "in_correct_marks": "0",
      "partial_marks": "0",
      "id_question_interpretation": "1",
      "id_comprehension": "0",
      "is_approved": "13",
      "question_image": "",
      "solution_image": "",
      "subject_name": "subject 1",
      "id_sub_subject": "112",
      "sub_subject_name": "Sub Subject 2",
      "id_topic": "212",
      "topic_name": "Sub subject 2 topic 1",
      "id_sub_topic": "31",
      "sub_topic_name": "subject 1 sub topic 2 Q3",
      "id_question_source": "3",
      "question_source_name": "Dakshana intimal\t",
      "id_difficult_level": "4",
      "difficulty_name": "Difficult",
      "quesion_pattern_name": "Single Correct Option Type ",
      "id_status": "0",
      "status_name": "Active",
      "last_review_date": "2018-10-31 11:05:14",
      "id_review_requirement": "2",
      "id_time_for_question": "2",
      "answer": "",
      "is_answered": "1",
      "is_visited": "1",
      "mark_for_review": "1",
      "is_not_answered": "1",
      "id_selected_option": "",
      "single_correct_option": "",
      "number_of_visted": "0",
      "spend_time": "0",
      "multiple_correct_option": "",
      "matxi_answer": "",
      "id_subject_section": "",
      "sequence_number": 1
    },
    {
      "id_question": "11",
      "id_subject": "6",
      "id_question_pattern": "1",
      "correct_marks": "2",
      "in_correct_marks": "1",
      "partial_marks": "0",
      "id_question_interpretation": "1",
      "id_comprehension": "0",
      "is_approved": "13",
      "question_image": "",
      "solution_image": "",
      "subject_name": "Mathematics",
      "id_sub_subject": "5",
      "sub_subject_name": "Algebra",
      "id_topic": "31",
      "topic_name": "Mathematical Induction",
      "id_sub_topic": "44",
      "sub_topic_name": "Mathematical induction 1",
      "id_question_source": "3",
      "question_source_name": "Dakshana intimal\t",
      "id_difficult_level": "3",
      "difficulty_name": "Medium",
      "quesion_pattern_name": "Single Correct Option Type ",
      "id_status": "0",
      "status_name": "Active",
      "last_review_date": "2018-10-24 16:20:13",
      "id_review_requirement": "1",
      "id_time_for_question": "3",
      "answer": "",
      "is_answered": "1",
      "is_visited": "1",
      "mark_for_review": "1",
      "is_not_answered": "1",
      "id_selected_option": "",
      "single_correct_option": "",
      "number_of_visted": "0",
      "spend_time": "0",
      "multiple_correct_option": "",
      "matxi_answer": "",
      "id_subject_section": "",
      "sequence_number": 2
    },
    {
      "id_question": "25",
      "id_subject": "4",
      "id_question_pattern": "1",
      "correct_marks": "2",
      "in_correct_marks": "0",
      "partial_marks": "0",
      "id_question_interpretation": "2",
      "id_comprehension": "0",
      "is_approved": "13",
      "question_image": "",
      "solution_image": "",
      "subject_name": "Chemistry",
      "id_sub_subject": "1",
      "sub_subject_name": "Optics",
      "id_topic": "1",
      "topic_name": "Thermo dynamics",
      "id_sub_topic": "46",
      "sub_topic_name": "sub topic thermodyn chemistry",
      "id_question_source": "3",
      "question_source_name": "Dakshana intimal\t",
      "id_difficult_level": "1",
      "difficulty_name": "Very Easy",
      "quesion_pattern_name": "Single Correct Option Type ",
      "id_status": "0",
      "status_name": "Active",
      "last_review_date": "2018-10-26 12:05:28",
      "id_review_requirement": "1",
      "id_time_for_question": "1",
      "answer": "",
      "is_answered": "1",
      "is_visited": "1",
      "mark_for_review": "1",
      "is_not_answered": "1",
      "id_selected_option": "",
      "single_correct_option": "",
      "number_of_visted": "0",
      "spend_time": "0",
      "multiple_correct_option": "",
      "matxi_answer": "",
      "id_subject_section": "",
      "sequence_number": 3
    },
    {
      "id_question": "6",
      "id_subject": "4",
      "id_question_pattern": "1",
      "correct_marks": "2",
      "in_correct_marks": "0",
      "partial_marks": "0",
      "id_question_interpretation": "2",
      "id_comprehension": "0",
      "is_approved": "13",
      "question_image": "",
      "solution_image": "",
      "subject_name": "Chemistry",
      "id_sub_subject": "1",
      "sub_subject_name": "Optics",
      "id_topic": "1",
      "topic_name": "Thermo dynamics",
      "id_sub_topic": "46",
      "sub_topic_name": "sub topic thermodyn chemistry",
      "id_question_source": "3",
      "question_source_name": "Dakshana intimal\t",
      "id_difficult_level": "2",
      "difficulty_name": "Easy",
      "quesion_pattern_name": "Single Correct Option Type ",
      "id_status": "0",
      "status_name": "Active",
      "last_review_date": "2018-10-24 16:15:48",
      "id_review_requirement": "1",
      "id_time_for_question": "2",
      "answer": "",
      "is_answered": "1",
      "is_visited": "1",
      "mark_for_review": "1",
      "is_not_answered": "1",
      "id_selected_option": "",
      "single_correct_option": "",
      "number_of_visted": "0",
      "spend_time": "0",
      "multiple_correct_option": "",
      "matxi_answer": "",
      "id_subject_section": "",
      "sequence_number": 4
    }       

  ]
```

I want to change `id_question` with `in_subject` every time.

```
foreach ($questions_array as $key => $row){
 $subject_sort[$key] = $row['id_subject'];
 $question_pattern_sort[$key] = $row['id_question_pattern'];
} 

array_multisort($question_pattern_sort, SORT_ASC, $subject_sort, SORT_ASC, $questions_array);
```

Comment: Please minimize your question to only include relevant sample data.  Your question will be just as clear with the identifying elements and a couple of randome elements in each subarray.  Listing tens of elements in each subarray is pure page bloat and makes your question less attractive to answer.  Then you should include your desired post-sort output so that it is clear about how your current code is not working and what you wish to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, what you can do is loop through your array and set `id_question = id_subject` for each element of the array.

Like so:

```
foreach($questions_array['questions'] as $key=>$value){

  $questions_array['questions'][$key]['id_question'] = $questions_array['questions'][$key]['id_subject'];  

}
```

Comment: foreach ($questions_array as $key => $row)
    {
     $subject_sort[$key] = $row['id_subject'];
     $question_pattern_sort[$key]  = $row['id_question_pattern'];
     
    }
    array_multisort($question_pattern_sort, SORT_ASC,$subject_sort, SORT_ASC,$questions_array);
 i do this but it give me same id_question every time

Comment: Please update your question with your current code.  The comment area is not appropriate for code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

To sort by `id_subject` then `id_question_pattern`, I can recommend one of two approaches (depending on your php version).

The spaceship operator with `usort()`: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/u7WhD))

```
usort($array["questions"], 
      function($a, $b){
          return [$a['id_subject'], $a['id_question_pattern']] <=> [$b['id_subject'], $b['id_question_pattern']];
      }
);
```

or with `array_multisort()` ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/f9Gb3))

```
array_multisort(array_column($array["questions"], "id_subject"), SORT_ASC, array_column($array["questions"], "id_question_pattern"), SORT_ASC, $array["questions"]);
```

Take care to realize that you are wanting to sort within the `questions` subarray.